# Email Template in Workflow Rule

Tags: workflow

I have created the New Email Template in workFlowRule ,whenever the Particular order gets activated the Email should be send to orders account address,cc address should be send to the current user login mail address and for particular order, attachment should also send to those users

Please guide me how to access the  orders attachment in email Template box in Workflow Rule,then How to set the from address and cc address for the Particular order gets activated

**Please show me the sample email template for the above Scenario:
How to access the orders attachment and how to set the from address and cc address for the particular order in Email Template Box
Guide me the sample template for the above Scenario

Comment: Can i paste the trigger code in Email Template box it will Work or Not

Comment: Guide Me sample template for my above scenario